# Get key name of array value in twig for loop

Tags: php, twig

I'm trying to have twig to output the key name(column name from mysql data).
What I want to do is basicly: `<a class="listquestions" href="#" id="{{ key }}"...`

Current codebase:

```
<table id="listquestions" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        {% for key, answer in answers[0] %}
            <th>{{ key }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 
    {% for key,answer in answers %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ answer.a_id }}</td>
            <td>
                <a class="listquestions" href="#" data-name="a_text" data-type="text" data-pk="{{ answer.a_id }}" data-url="{{ path_for('qa.edit') }}" data-title="enter attribute name">
                    {{ answer.a_text }}
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="listquestions" href="#" data-name="a_attribute_name" data-type="text" data-pk="{{ answer.a_id }}" data-url="{{ path_for('qa.edit') }}" data-title="enter attribute name">
                    {{ answer.a_attribute_name}}
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

PHP function var_export($data,true) outputs:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'a_id' => '1',
    'a_text' => 'text',
    'a_attribute_name' => 'attr',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'a_id' => '2',
    'a_text' => 'text',
    'a_attribute_name' => 'attr',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'a_id' => '3',
    'a_text' => 'text',
    'a_attribute_name' => 'attr',
  ),
)
```

I tried adding a TwigExtension that does `key($answer.a_text)` but `key()` does not work with twig for-loops.

So what am I missing? I can output the key name inside `<thead>` as you see but I'd like to do this with the second for-loop.

Comment: And what is the problem? I don't see `id="{{ key }}"` in your code

Comment: I think it has something to do with nested arrays, I'm only itterating over $arr[0] in the <thead>, `{{ key }}` only outputs `"0","1","2"...`

Comment: What is the expected content of `key` then? Imho for this situation you'll need to specify the key manually

Comment: I think you have to use a second for loop for your fields: `{% for key,answer in answers %} <tr> {% for field,value in answer %} {% if field = 'a_id' %} <td></td> {% else %} <td><a/></td>`

Comment: @DarkBee I have it hardcoded in the codebase, it's supposed to be one of either `a_id, a_text, a_attribute_name` .

Comment: As pointed out by @copynpaste you would need to create a second loop to achieve this. Do note, `id`'s in HTML need to be unique, which in your case is false. You would need to add an unique indentifier to the `id` like the `answer.id`

Comment: Ok, I'm all out of ideas how to create this loop, there has to be a neater solution other than filling up my template with if-else statements. Edited from `id` to `data-name`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table id="listquestions" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        {% for key, answer in answers[0] %}
            <th>{{ key }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 
    {% for key,answer in answers %}
        {% for field, value in answer %}
        <tr>
           {% if field == 'a_id' %}
            <td>{{ answer.a_id }}</td>
            {% else %}
            <td>
                <a class="listquestions" href="#" data-name="{{ field }}" data-type="text" data-pk="{{ answer.a_id }}" data-url="path_for('qa.edit')" data-title="enter attribute name">
                    {{ value }}
                </a>
            </td>
            {% endif %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```